# Parse large amount of JSON data with swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I've got to fetch a large amount of data from a remote web server. I decided to use Alamofire for the HTTP request and Swifty JSON to parse JSON response. When the process ends I return back data to a `UITableViewController` and I feed my table view. Due to the size of JSON (1.5 MB), bind process to object model requires additional time.
Here an example of how I handle the process in my code:

Example of object model:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class Course {
    var id: String!
    var students: [JSON]
    var hours: [JSON]
    var related: [JSON]

    init?(_ key: String, json: JSON) {
        self.id = key
        self.students = json["students"].arrayValue
        self.calendar = json["calendar"].arrayValue
        self.relatedCourses = json["related_courses"].arrayValue
    }
}
```

Example of Alamofire request:

```
func fetchAllData(data: Data, completion: @escaping ([String:[String:Any]], [JSON]) -> ()) {) {
        let url = "http://myapi/data" // includes courses

        Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON(queue: utilityQueue) {
                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let responseData):
                    let (results, order) = self.parseResults(json: JSON(responseData))
                    completion(results, order)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    AppDelegate.print(value: error)
                    break
                }
        }
    }
```

Example of JSON parsing:

```
func parseResults(json: JSON) -> ([String:[String:Any]], [JSON]){
            var results = [String:[String:Any]]()
            results["courses"] = getCourses(from: json)
            results["students"] = getStudents(from: json)
            ... I parse other elements here
            return (results, order)
        }

func getCourses(from json: JSON) -> [String:Course] {
    var courses = [String:Course]()
    for (key, data) : (String, JSON) in json["courses"] {
        courses[key] = Course(key, json: data)!
    }
    return places
}
```

I used dictionaries in order to reduce time complexity to access elements. I've got lots of informations to join.

Here TableViewController methods:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        // Call here fetch method
        ResultsService().fetchResults(data: data, completion: {
            (results, order) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.courses = results["courses"]!
                self.students = results["students"]!
                ...
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CourseCell", for: indexPath) as! CourseCell

        let course = courses[orderedCourses[indexPath.row].stringValue] as! Course
        let bestStudent = students[course.students[0].stringValue] as! Student

        cell.courseName.text = course.name
        cell.bestStudentScore.text = bestStudent.score
        ...

        return cell
    }
```

Everything is working fine, but I have to wait 3 or 4 seconds in order to get data displayed in table view. With a little bit of debugging I've pointed out that my bottleneck is binding JSON to objects. Do you have any suggestion useful to improve performances? I was thinking about something like: starting to parse JSON, return small chunks of data and display it in table view but I don't know exactly how to achieve this goal. I can't use pagination so I have to fetch whole data from web server and try to optimise everything from a client point of view. Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. When measuring performance, you should however ensure that you are profiling your code with optimisations enabled, e.g. use the Release configuration. Also, use Instruments to get accurate data. I fear, though, that you have already correctly identified the main cause of the problem. I would try to switch from SwiftyJSON to another JSON library, e.g. Marshal or Genome and try those. All three use NSJSONSerialisation under the hood in order to get a "Foundation representation", but SwiftyJSON is known to be a bit slow.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I really want to thank you for your answer. I decided to use Marshal in order to parse JSON (it seems to be the best library based on this benchmark github.com/bwhiteley/JSONShootout/issues) and loading time decreased from 3 seconds to 1 second. Unfortunately it's still too much. I'm thinking about some kind of observable array.

Comment: I would expect, `NSJSONSerialisation` creates a representation from a 1 MByte JSON in about 30 ms on a device. Can you confirm this, please? Creating your model objects from a NSDictionary (using Marshall, Genome or whatever) may add an additional duration of (max) 100 ms. So, there's still something eating CPU cycles for nothing   :)

Comment: I did a little benchmark, NSJSONSerialization took about 400ms to create a representation. After that I mapped it in 6 different dictionaries, and it took about 1.5 seconds more or less :(

Comment: To be honest, that sounds strange. I made a benchmark test myself, on an iPhone 7, testing a given Data with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])`. Using [twitter_timeline.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amamchur/iJSONBenchmark/master/payload/twitter_timeline.json) the result is: `measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.001, relative standard deviation: 9.986%, values: [0.001206, 0.001009, 0.000993, 0.001006, 0.000992, 0.001017, 0.001181, 0.001234, 0.001230, 0.001260]` . That is, roughly 1 ms for a 1/4 Mbyte JSON.

Comment: Correction: the JSON file is not 250kByte, but 42kByte. So, 1 Mbyte would take roughly 25 ms.